# Missing Import Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClrVerticalNavGroup -> VerticalNavGroupRegistrationService]:

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm using a `<clr-vertical-nav-group>` component from [Clarity.design](https://clarity.design/) and I'm currently receiving this error in my angular app

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClrVerticalNavGroup ->
>   VerticalNavGroupRegistrationService]

I’m missing an import in my app module, but I’m having a hard time figuring out what I need to import. Importing `ClrVerticalNavGroup` does nothing and importing `VerticalNavGroupRegistrationService` gives me a **"can’t resolve service in app”** error.

My app module

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ClarityModule,
    ClrVerticalNavModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    VerticalNavGroupRegistrationService,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

After importing `VerticalNavGroupRegistrationService` I would expect the error to go away, but instead I end up getting

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve
>   '@clr/angular/layout/vertical-nav/providers/vertical-nav-group-registration.service'
>   in '../src/app'

Comment: Do you get any errors on build time?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @ahmeticat `ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@clr/angular/layout/vertical-nav/providers/vertical-nav-group-registration.service' in '../src/app'` is the actual build error.  @Narm, I'm using version `7.2`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/efuentesp/rdl2-angular-clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/layout/vertical-nav/vertical-nav.ts) is ClrVerticalNav providing this service on its own. No need for you to provide it. ClrVerticalNavGroup does not so, but is used within ClrVerticalNav only.

Comment: @doubleya - did this address your issue?